# Empty value in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I can't believe I forgot this, what is in an `NSArray` if there's no value in the field (this is being determined by loading a .plist file).  I know I should know this, but right now I'm having a serious brain fart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty value is represented by [`NSNull`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

or just an empty `NSArray`, or even `nil`.